# Работа с БД. Хочу использовать баллы из таблицы, но они выводятся как символ в коде

Tags: python, база-данных

[image: Таблица из БД]

```
import bd_table
import datetime
import sqlite3


connect = sqlite3.connect('coin_bonus.db')
cursor = connect.cursor()

coin_cost = cursor.execute(f'SELECT sum(SummaryMoney) FROM Summary_process_in').fetchone()

today = datetime.date.today()
## Почему-то берет число как символ
#[дата-курс]

bd_table.cost_coin_list =[today, coin_cost*5]
#bd_table.write_data_cost()
print(bd_table.cost_coin_list)
```

Хочу взять сумму чисел из столбика, а потом пропускать его через вычисления. С помощью чего автоматом заполнять другие таблицы.

[image: Таблица]

Comment: `coin_cost = float(coin_cost)`, например. Хотя вопрос не совсем понятен

Comment: Выводит ошибку.
coin_cost = float(coin_cost)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'tuple'
[Finished in 430ms]

Суть в том, что я получаю символ, а не число, с которым можно было бы работать
Сложить числа из БД мне удаётся, но дальше дело не идёт. Его нельзя умножить или разделить и т.п.

Без float получается следующее:
[datetime.date(2021, 12, 30), (11, 11, 11, 11, 11)]
[Finished in 416ms]
Одиннадцать - сумма тех чисел из столбца, но вот они в коде получаются, как отдельный символ (не подходящий формат)

Comment: Ну тогда возьмите `float(coin_cost[0])`, там кортеж из одного элемента. Если умножать кортеж, его значения размножаются в более широкий кортеж с тем же значением. Просто возьмите первый элемент (с индексом 0) из кортежа.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема лежала в том, что столбы имели русское наименование и по коду это распознаётся